# Numpy: two versions of matrix multiplication, same operands but speed is very different why?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

```
import numpy as np
import time
X = np.random.randn(200, 200)
Y = np.random.randn(200, 200)

#version 1
def judge(x):
    if x>0:
        return 1
    return x
convert = np.frompyfunc(judge,1,1)
C = convert(Y)
t1 = time.time()
r = X.dot(C)
t2 = time.time()
print t2-t1      #0.479473829269

#version 2
Y[Y>0] = 1
print C==Y       #True
t1 = time.time()
r = X.dot(Y)
t2 = time.time()
print t2-t1      #0.00127196311951
```

Despite the two operands are the same, version 1 took 0.479s while version 2 took 0.001s and is 478 times faster than version 1. Why?

Comment: First one is Object type array and as such would be slow. Go through the linked dup for more info.

Comment: It's easy to overlook this  little line in the `frompyfunc` docs: `The returned ufunc always returns PyObject arrays`.  You need something like `C = convert(Y).astype(int)` to get something like `Y`.  (`C==Y` just tests the equality of the elements, not 'sameness' of the arrays).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Now I understand the differences